# CSS Dotted Line in the box is messed up at the corner and looks weird

Tags: html, css

I am using css for dotted line:

Problem is that Dotted Line in the box is messed up at the corner and looks weird:

CSS CODE IS:

```
.dotted-box {
    border: 3px dotted #4a4a49;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    margin: 69px auto 10px !important;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 75% !important;
}
```

[Please check this on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbgB4/32/)

IT should be look like following image:
[image]

Is there anyway to solve this issue?

Comment: so what should it look like?

Comment: @KingKing i've added image for your reference. I need it like this

Comment: @Husen unless your div has fixed size so that we can choose the best width and height for your div. Otherwise we don't have any way to render it perfectly like that unless playing with some JS.

Comment: IMHO `border-radius: 4px;` makes it a bit better (not perfect), nothing else can be done for a dynamic box I think, tho. http://jsfiddle.net/gbgB4/33/

Comment: Chrome and FF 30 have a known Bug when giving border `dotted`.